# Log in asking for login in on every screen in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, authentication, middleware, laravel-5.3

I'm updating my app to Laravel 5.3 and having a lot of trouble with middleware.

Every time I go to a route that is protected, it asks me to log in.

All of my protected routes are in a route group:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function()
{
    // all routes here
});
```

I've also tried:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function()
```

And:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function()
```

I've also tried adding ->middleware('auth') to the end of the individual routes. I've even done a clean Laravel install and added routes one at a time until I found the problem. That problem is, unfortunately, navigating between auth routes.

Nothing is helping.

Does anyone have any advice? I'm at a standstill updating my app until I get this solved.

Comment: did u check your session is creating or not?

Comment: It doesn't look like it is. If I log in, it takes me to the admin page. If I reload the admin page, it asks me to log in again.

How do I fix this? Why wouldn't it be creating a session right out of the box? I haven't changed anything related to this.

Comment: Config/session.php can you please update the  'lifetime' => 120, value and check once.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. It was at 120 when I opened the file.

Comment: hi, can you try once with table, I mean to store session in table so that we can identify that issue in creating session or somewhere else

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session

Comment: All right. I changed it and when I log in, nothing is created in the table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122569/discussion-between-ravi-shankar-and-jerauf).

Comment: @RaviShankar. Please do post the answer when the question has been resolved. :)

Comment: Was the answer ever found? If so, are these routes setup in api.php or web.php?

Comment: It's actually that I was using Auth::logout() in my logout link. That was killing the session when the page loaded.

Comment: OMG @jerauf I know this is an old post but this exactly the problem I was having for *days* thank you sooo much!